# Check Camera Orientation

Tags: android, cordova

How do I check camera orientation for landscape or portrait continuously in phonegap android?

I am using cordova2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourfunction()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        alert('landscape');
        break; 
      default:
        alert('portrait');
        break; 
    }
  }

window.addEventListener('onorientationchange', yourfunction);
```